# How can I retrieve the YouTube comments that are held for review

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to retrieve all of the comments that are held for review. I am able to get the top-level comments by using the commentThreads().list() function, but need to get the replies to the top-level comments that are held for review. I used the comments().list() method to get the replies to the top-level comments. I am able to get the replies, but all of them were published comments. None of the comments that are held for review were retrieved, which is puzzling. Is this how it's supposed to be? I do not need the published comments, I just need the ones that are held for review. I tried to request the comments that are held for review, but kept getting the following error:

```
mod     = item['snippet']['moderationStatus']
KeyError: 'moderationStatus'
```

Not sure what to do to get relies that are held for review.

---

```
def get_comments(service, parent_id, threadId, comments):
  results = service.comments().list(
    part                = "snippet, id",
    parentId            = parent_id,
    textFormat          = "plainText"
  ).execute()

  for item in results['items']:
    cid     = item['id']
    text    = item['snippet']['textDisplay']
    mod     = item['snippet']['moderationStatus']  
    # ^ The line above generates an error: KeyError: 'moderationStatus'
    # If I delete the "mod =..." and the "if mod !=..." lines, I get all 
    # of the replies to the top-level comment (parentId) that have been 
    # published but none of the ones that are held for review. 
    if mod != "heldForReview":
        comments.append([text, cid])

  return comments
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a query parameter `moderationStatus` you can use to get comments held for review. I think you just need to set `moderationStatus= heldForReview`

See the doc here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/

And your query would look like this

```
curl \
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&moderationStatus=heldForReview&videoId=[VIDEO_ID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--compressed
```